# Error while trying to print out arraylist

Tags: java, debugging

The error I am reviving is  "void type is not allowed here "  how would I fix this error in order to print out my array list.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;



public class Library
{


    private ArrayList<Member>listOfMembers;
    public Library()
    {
        listOfMembers = new ArrayList<Member>();
    }
    public void storeMember(Member Member)
    {
        listOfMembers.add(Member);
    }
    public int numberOfMembers()
    {
        return listOfMembers.size();
    }

    public void listMembers()
   {
   for (int item=0; item<listOfMembers.size(); item++ ) {
     Member m = listOfMembers.get (item);
    System.out.println(m.GetWholeName());
        }
    } 


}
```

---

and here is my member class just in case you need it

```
class Member
{
    // The fields.
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Integer number;
    private Integer id;

    /**

     hehe
     */
    public Member(String firstName, String lastName, Integer telNumber, Integer memberId)
    {
        firstname = firstName;
        lastname = lastName;
        number = telNumber;
        id = memberId;

    }


    // Add the methods here ...
    public void GetWholeName(){

    System.out.println(firstname + (" ") + lastname);

}
}
```

I'm trying to print the first and last name of my member class by using an array list in my library class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to print out the result of `m.GetWholeName()` which returns void. Change `GetWholeName` to return a `String` instead, or simply call `GetWholeName` as it's already printing the name to standard out although that behavior doesn't quite match up to the behavior the name would imply.

```
public String GetWholeName() {

    return firstname + " " + lastname;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Member class change this:

```
System.out.println(firstname + (" ") + lastname);
```

to this:

```
return firstname + " " + lastname;
```